# SSIS: Truncate table statement causing LCK_M_SCH_S lock on the table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, deadlock, locks

I have an SSIS package that consist of 2 main blocks within Begin and Commit/Rollback transaction blocks
1. Truncate tables (with truncate table query)
2. Import Data (Import data from flat file and insert to these truncated tables)

When I run the package the job is getting hung. The activity monitor shows that there is a LCK_M_SCH_S lock created that blocks further execution.

Sometimes this work and sometimes not. 
To add, if I truncate these table separately and run the package removing the truncate block it executes fine. [image: Activity Monitor on Lock]

Also to add there are not just one Import Data component. We have around 6 import data component for 6 different table. For time being i kept only one in the screen shot

[image: Control flow] ,

[image: Data flow for Import Data component]

Comment: Let us know old version and new version of SSIS. Please paste exact error message. Any screenshot will be helpful.

Comment: @BhatiaAshish: I am not getting any error. it just hang. Also I checked old version it too fails. Now the package is with latest SSIS version

Comment: Check which query is blocking the truncate statement. On your screen it says session 84 is the one that's blocking your operation. If you are doing another operation like insert, update (or the like) on the table you are trying to truncate, it will get stuck untill that operation ends and it's commited.

Comment: How can we keep it wait till the truncate is complete.

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci: the detail says the query as : sys.sp_describe_first_result_set;1

Comment: How are you issuing the truncate statements? Are they both in one `Execute SQL` task? Separate ones? Something other than an `Execute SQL` task? Also, based on your last statement that it's waiting on `sp_describe_first_result_set`, check to make sure that the "Result Set" property of the task is "None".

Comment: There are multiple truncate statements inside one sql task.. Apart from that Execute Sql tak I have Import data block that will import data from flat file to OLEDB destination.

Comment: @BenThul : here are multiple truncate statements inside one sql task.. Apart from that Execute Sql tak I have Import data block that will import data from flat file to OLEDB destination. Also for what component you want the result set to None

Comment: @user2081126: no result sets for the truncate tables task. I'm with billinkc in wanting to see a data flow.

Comment: @billinkc : Screen shot updated

Comment: @BenThul : Screen shot updated

Comment: @BenThul: Also to add there are not just one Import Data component. We have around 6 import data component for 6 different table. For time being i kept only one in the screen shot

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci:Also to add there are not just one Import Data component. We have around 6 import data component for 6 different table. For time being i kept only one in the screen shot

Comment: @user2081126 Having 6 different flows or 1 is the same if they work with independent transactions each (and on different tables/objects). sp_describe_first_result_set is used to retrieve metadata for a query and it's possible that the SSIS uses it to validate your table's columns before doing the insert from the flat file. Check which user and session is issuing that command when it's blocked; if it's the same as your DTS user/session then it's a problem with the data validation between SSIS packages.

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci: Yes they are with same login ID. To add, if I remove the Truncate block and do that manually and then run the package, it runs without any issues

Comment: Check all your database connections on your DTS (and other DTS if they run simultaneously) and make sure that DelayValidation is set to True on all of them. The truncate is being blocked by the data validation query. Also, sometimes the DTS keeps some deleted connections or flows on it's structure, as last resource, try building the same DTS from scratch. billinkc already mentioned this on his answer, I can't think of any other solution unfortunately D:

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci: Tried this. but not working. Is there any way we can stop the other action to wait after the truncate is complete so that lock created by truncate will be released by then.

Comment: The only other option I can think of is using moving your Data Flow into another package and executing that package inside this one (transaction should be propagated).

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci: do you mean creating a new SSIS package for Data flow?

Comment: Yes, but it's a very last resort D:

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your screenshots, the first thing I'd verify is that the property RetainSameConnection is set to true on your OLE DB Connection manager (right click on CM, select Properties, find RetainSameConnection). The default for this is False.

If that resolves the issue, then the root cause was you had two requests in different transactions attempting to modify the same resource.

If you had already switched the Connection Manager's property to true, then my next guess would be that you want to set the DelayValidation property for the Data Flow "Import Data" to True.

If that resolves the issue, then the root cause was the component was attempting to validate the metadata for the target table and was getting blocked by the truncate statement (or vice versa). Setting DelayValidation will prevent the package from validating that specific task until the last possible second - giving other processes time to get out of the way. This seems less likely but it's the only other opportunity for the package to be blocking itself.

Comment: RetainSameConnection is already set to True. And I turned on DelayValidation for the Data flow Ïmport Data. Still getting stuck.

Comment: Also i tried to set this which you mentioned in the following link. Both doesn't seems to work : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595871/ssis-truncate-with-in-a-transaction

Comment: Also to add there are not just one Import Data component. We have around 6 import data component for 6 different table. For time being i kept only one in the screen shot

Comment: Oh, ok. So, if you run the package as depicted in your screenshots, then does it block itself? (Disable the other data flows to test)

Comment: If I run with just 2 blocks enabled then it run fine.

Comment: Also when it is locked both the SPID detail gives the following query: sys.sp_describe_first_result_set;1

Comment: Also if we are running this without Begin/Commit transaction then it will work fine

Comment: Any luck? Tried all those scenarios. Still breaking